# JQuery HTML Table Filter not filtering

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-table

I am using the example Individual column searching from [DataTables.Net](https://datatables.net/examples/api/multi_filter_select.html) which works for the most part, however, I have two fields that it will not filter on.

I believe its down to there being a FontAwesome icon in the field too.

This is the HTML for one of the table columns that is not filtering, the other is virtualy the same so if i can get this one working, the other one should too.

```
<td class='ReportManager'>
    <span style='opacity: 0.349019607843137; font-size: 20px;'>
        <i class='fa fa-file-o'></i>
    </span></br>
    81
</td>
```

I suspect if I strip out the icon, this would work, but I need the icon in there, and for the filter to work.

Any and all help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Well did you try stripping the icon as you said to see if it works? that would narrow down your problem.

Comment: I am trying this now

Comment: @callback yes, stripping out the icon works as expected, but the icon needs to be there as per client request

Comment: Why dont you have the icon as an `<img>` and just place it on the field, this way it does not interfere with the field data.

Comment: its not a locally held icon, its one that is being referenced from FontAwsome CSS, and would fall outside of the standards I am being held to for this project.

Comment: @callback wouldnt that cause the same issue that I am having if i did that anyway?

Answer (score 0):

After scratching my head, and looking at this in a fiddle (where this annoyingly worked) I output the value that the filter was looking for, then compared against the html that was being written.

The JavaScript was looking for a `<br>` tag rather then a `<br/>` or `<\br>` tag.